# While loop not returning correct output when nested

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

I have a while loop that is supposed to first get the `individual_id` from a table called submittedresume using the job_id that it gets from another function. It would then use that id in another while loop to get the `first_name` and `last_name` from the individual table. It would then use another while loop to get the `submitted_id` from the submitted resume table.

I split the first and last while loop to get distinct values from the output.

My first while loop. It first gets the `individual_id` from a table called submittedresume using the job_id that it gets from another function. It gives me the correct output of two user ids: 9 and 4.

```
 global $database;
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT individual_id FROM submittedresume WHERE job_post_id='$id'";
    $output = $database->query($query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($output)) {
        $indvId = $row[0];
    }
```

This is the second inner while loop. It gives me an output of Mary Jane (No repeat) and Tom Sawyer.

```
 $indvId = $row[0];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM individual WHERE individual_id='$indvId'";
        $result = $database->query($sql);                
        while ($details = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
            $first = $details['first_name'];
            $last = $details['last_name'];
            echo $first;
            echo $last;
        }
```

This is my whole function:

```
public function displayApplications($id){
    global $database;
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT individual_id FROM submittedresume WHERE job_post_id='$id'";
    $output = $database->query($query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($output)) {
        $indvId = $row[0];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM individual WHERE individual_id='$indvId'";
        $result = $database->query($sql);                
        while ($details = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  
            $first = $details['first_name'];
            $last = $details['last_name'];
            $sqlquery = "SELECT DISTINCT resume_title FROM submittedresume WHERE individual_id='$indvId' order by submitted_id";
            $data = $database->query($sqlquery); 
            if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 0) {
                    echo "Database is empty <br>";
                } else {
                     while (($name = mysqli_fetch_array($data))) {
                           echo $first . " " . $last . " "."<a href=handleDownload.php?id=$id>$name[0]</a><br>";
                       }
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I'm getting right now:

```
first_name | last_name | resume_name
Mary       | Jane      | resume_1
Mary       | Jane      | resume_2
```

This is what I'm looking for:

```
first_name | last_name | resume_name
Mary       | Jane      | resume_2
Tom        | Sawyer    | resume_1
```

Comment: you need to rewrite your queries and use `JOIN` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think after `while` use `foreach` loop:

For example:

```
 $query = "SELECT DISTINCT individual_id FROM submittedresume WHERE job_post_id='$id'";
$output = $database->query($query);
$details = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 foreach($details as $key => $value){
       echo 'Key: '. $key . ' '. 'Value: '. $value;
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting double output when using foreach. Is there a way for me to remove the doubles? Key: 0 Value: 4Key: individual_id Value: 4Key: 0 Value: 9Key: individual_id Value: 9

Comment: I've updated my answer. I guess it's my wrong to use while inside a `foreach` loop because `while` loops every data that queries

Answer (score 0):

`$indvId = $row[0];` is returning the 1st item in the result array

I personally would use a foreach loop but you could do it the way you have it by adding a counter ie: `$count = 0;` before the loop and `$count++;` inside the loop and `$indvId = $row[$i];`

Comment: The foreach method sounds interesting. If I were to use foreach, how would I go about it?

Comment: can you post print_r($output) so I can see what the array looks like?